# sqlmap injection question

Tags: sqlmap

I'm trying to test my website, the command is: `sqlmap -u website -D sitedb -T table -C column --dump --threads 10`. While sqlmap is retrieving data it displays:

```
[19:36:55] [INFO] retrieved: "","",
[19:36:56] [INFO] retrieved: "","",
[19:36:56] [INFO] retrieved: "","",
[19:36:56] [INFO] retrieved: "","",
[19:36:56] [INFO] retrieved: "","",
[19:36:56] [INFO] retrieved: "","",
[19:36:56] [INFO] retrieved: "","",
```

Some real data appears but most of the data is just `"","",`. Why is this happening?

Comment: Since this is your website it would be helpful to see the apache logs and the code snippet that you are testing

Comment: Can you please put in the entire command, minus the website name? It would help to see more information.

Comment: is it also possible that the tables contain null data fields?